# Identity UpdateAsync lose IdentityResult.Failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I've wrote a custom UserStore for the ASP.NET Identity which I'm using it in an ASP.NET MVC 5.1 application. Everything is working as expected and I'm very happy with this new feature (Identity) of ASP.NET...

The issue is that I think is almost 2 days since I'm trying to return an error from the UpdateAsync method and somehow it seems that I'm not able to return anything.

LE: I'm using ASP.NET Identity Core 2.0.0-beta1

This is my code in few lines:

```
public Task UpdateAsync(IdentityUser user)
{
    AdminUserEntity userEntity = new AdminUserEntity();
    userEntity.IsNew = false;
    userEntity.Id = user.UserModel.Id;
    userEntity.UserCompleteName = user.UserModel.UserCompleteName;
    userEntity.IsDisabled = user.UserModel.IsDisabled;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.UserModel.PasswordHash))
        userEntity.PasswordHash = user.UserModel.PasswordHash;

    if (user.Claims != null && user.Claims.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Claim claim in user.Claims)
        {
            AdminUserClaimEntity claimEntity = userEntity.AdminUserClaims.AddNew();
            claimEntity.AdminUserUniqueId = user.UserModel.UniqueId;
            claimEntity.ClaimType = claim.Type;
            claimEntity.ClaimValue = claim.Value;
        }
    }

    try
    {
        byte[] timestamp = Convert.FromBase64String(user.UserModel.Timestamp);
        AdminUserEntityManagement.UpdateCompleteAdminUserEntity(userEntity, timestamp);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        List<string> errors = new List<string>() {exception.Message};
        return Task.FromResult<IdentityResult>(IdentityResult.Failed(errors.ToArray()));
    }

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

Though there is an exception and the catch block is getting executed, the following line always returns success:

```
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(identityUser);
```

Can someone please tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, @hao-kung, thank you for your help. Now I can say that I've seen the big picture. Though I can't say that I like it, I understood how UserManager is working.

Also, if you think that I'm saying something wrong, please, correct me.

For the others, in order to customize UserManager behavior (even if you just want to surface an error which you are anyway able to catch in the UserStore custom class) you have to follow these steps (for better understanding I will exemplify by describing what I've did to catch a business exception for the UpdateAsync method and show it in the interface):

1. In the UserStore class (which should implement among other interfaces the IUserStore interface), don't catch any exception.

   ```
   public Task UpdateAsync(IdentityUser user)
   {
       // here an exception will be thrown if there is a concurrency issue
       byte[] timestamp = Convert.FromBase64String(user.UserModel.Timestamp);
       AdminUserEntityManagement.UpdateCompleteAdminUserEntity(userEntity, timestamp);
       return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
   }
   ```
2. Extend UserManager class and override the method that you want to customize (catch the business exception thrown earlier and surface it to the interface):

   ```
   public class AdminUserManager : UserManager<IdentityUser>


   public override async Task<IdentityResult> UpdateAsync(IdentityUser user)
   {
       Task<IdentityResult> result = base.UpdateAsync(user);

       try
       {
           IdentityResult identityResult = await result;
       }
       catch (Exception exception)
       {
           List<string> errors = new List<string>() { exception.Message };
           return IdentityResult.Failed(errors.ToArray());
       }

       return result.Result;
   }
   ```
3. In the MVC controller (for example) read the result of the UpdateAsync method from the extended UserManager class:

   ```
   IdentityResult result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(identityUser);
   if (result.Succeeded)
   {
     this.SetNotification("The user has been updated.", EnumToastrNotificationType.Info);
     return RedirectToAction("ShowUsers", "UserManagement");
   }
   else
   {
     this.AddErrors(result);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this UpdateAsync is in your ApplicationUserManager class, shouldn't the signature be

```
public override Task<IdentityResult> UpdateAsync
```

if you are trying to change how the UserManager's UpdateAsync method works.

Comment: No - The UpdateAsync is taken from the UserStore class, which implements the necesary interfaces (public class UserStore :        IUserStore<IdentityUser>, IUserClaimStore<IdentityUser>, IUserLoginStore<IdentityUser>, IUserRoleStore<IdentityUser>, IUserPasswordStore<IdentityUser>, IUserSecurityStampStore<IdentityUser>).

Comment: Ah that explains it then, the contract between the UserManager and UserStore is exceptions, if something bad happens where you want to return an identityResult, you need to handle that at the Usermanager level.  The UserManager assumes that if no exception was thrown, the operation completed successfully for Update.  You have to override this behavior on the UserManager if you want to trap exceptions and turn those into IdentityResult.Failures that get surfaced to the app.

Comment: Then I have other two questions: a) this means that I have to implement my own UserManager? if yes, why? I'm asking this because from my understanding, the UserManager is a layer over the UserStore, RoleStore, etc which is not necesary to overwrite with a custom implementation; b) why the UpdateAsync method still have a return parameter when that value isn't used anyway? Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to reimplement, you can extend and override the one method if you want, it doesn't have a return parameter, Task is the async equivalent of void.

Comment: So, I've extended UserManager<IdentityUser> into a class called AdminUserManager and in the public override Task<IdentityResult> UpdateAsync(IdentityUser user) I've put the base.UpdateAsync(user); into a try / catch block... The exception is not caught at all... Have any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: public override Task<IdentityResult> UpdateAsync(IdentityUser user)
        {
            Task<IdentityResult> result = Task.FromResult<IdentityResult>(IdentityResult.Success);

            try
            {
                result = base.UpdateAsync(user);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                List<string> errors = new List<string>() { exception.Message };
                return Task.FromResult<IdentityResult>(IdentityResult.Failed(errors.ToArray()));
            }
            
            return result;
        }

Comment: You should be able to step into both your Store Update and AdminUserManager to see what's going on